# How to install driver for "canon i-sensys mf 3010"?

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I have Ubuntu 14.04 , and i have a printer "canon i-sensys mf 3010"
how to install a "driver" of this  printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canon i-SENSYS MF3010](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf3010.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(32-bit))

File version

2.70

Release date

16 July 2015

Operating system(s)

Linux (32-bit)

Linux (64-bit)

UFRII/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux v2.70

resoure : https://www.canon-europe.com/support/

---

Download and install. also you can use this app :
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/system-config-printer-gnome/